# PyInstaller Error: got multiple values for keyword argument 'hiddenimports'

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

I'm trying to package my app with PyInstaller. Its made with Kivy and then when i run PyInstaller command with my .spec file, this throw an error, see in next image.

[image]

So i read about the hiddenimports and try to add submodules that maybe they aren't visibles for the app but i got the same error. I don't know which values it expects.

This is my tree directory, the main.py its the main file xd.

[image]

And main.py contains:

```
import os, sys
from kivy.resources import resource_add_path
from controllers.corecontroller import CoreController
from views.app import PassEwokApp

workspace=os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())

if __name__=="__main__":
    resource_add_path(os.path.join(workspace,"resources"))
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
         resource_add_path(os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS))
    app=PassEwokApp()
    controller=CoreController(app)
    controller.start()
```

And my .spec file contains:

```
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
from kivy.tools.packaging.pyinstaller_hooks import get_deps_minimal, hookspath, 
runtime_hooks

from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules

submodules = collect_submodules('controllers')
submodules += collect_submodules('models')
submodules += collect_submodules('views')
submodules += collect_submodules('utilities')
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
         pathex=['D:\\Python\\kivy\\passewok\\'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=submodules,
         hookspath=hookspath(),
         hooksconfig={},
         runtime_hooks=runtime_hooks(),
                     **get_deps_minimal(video=None,audio=None),
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
splash = Splash('.\\resources\\app-200x200.png',
            binaries=a.binaries,
            datas=a.datas,
            text_pos=None,
            text_size=12,
            minify_script=True)

exe = EXE(pyz,Tree('D:\\Python\\kivy\\passewok\\'),
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas, 
      splash, 
      splash.binaries,
      *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
      name='Passewok',
      debug=False,
      bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      upx_exclude=[],
      runtime_tmpdir=None,
      console=False,
      disable_windowed_traceback=False,
      target_arch=None,
      codesign_identity=None,
      entitlements_file=None , icon='resources\\app-200x200.ico')
```

Comment: Based on this, the only possibility is that `get_deps_minimal` from Kivy is also setting `hiddenimports`.  You may need to remove yours, or fetch theirs into a local dictionary and modify it, if it doesn't already contain what you need.

Comment: @TimRoberts yeah, you're right, `get_deps_minimal` was returning its own hiddenimports, thanks